# Can I put in a jLabel text from a database?

Tags: java, database, netbeans, jlabel

I need some help with a little project that I have to do for work. In this project I need to get a specific cell from the database, the query must look someting like this `select * from app_1 where id_user_main=?`

```java
jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
jLabel4.setText(null);
{
    String sql = "select * from info where id_user_main=?";  
    try {
        conn = MySQLConnect.ConnectDb();
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setInt(1, id);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) { 
            jLabel4.setText(rs.getString("info"));
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply split your problem in two sub problems:

- Retrieve the string from the database
- Set the string to the label

As an example:

```
 public String getStringFromDb(String key) {
     ....
 }

 ....

 public void setLabel(String str, JLabel label) {
     label.setText(str);
 }

 ...

 public void setLabelFromDb(String key, JLabel label) {
     String str = getStringFromDb(key);
     setLabel(str, label);
 }
```

Comment: Thy, but i am very new working with java and i use netbeans, if you cant be more explicit pleas, thy for the fast respond.

Comment: but i use netbeans and I do not know where to put that code.